# React access sub-components properties in main component

Tags: reactjs

Would it be possible to access a sub-components properties in the main component in React?

For example I'm trying this: I've got a main component *MyComponent* and a *SubComp* sub-component that renders a button. Would it be possible to set the state of *MyComponent* equal to the *tex* property of the clicked *SubComp*?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'Initial State'
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({name: SubComp.tex});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SubComp onClick={this.handleClick} tex="but1"/>
        <SubComp onClick={this.handleClick} tex="but2"/>
        <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

class SubComp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  };
  render(){
    return(
      <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Click Me</button>
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried to do it in the *handleClick* method with *SubComp.tex* but it's obviously not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the `tex` prop in `SubComp` via the callback:

```
render() {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => this.props.onClick(this.props.tex)}>Click Me</button>
  );
}
```

And use it in the `handleClick` of `MyComponent`:

```
handleClick(tex) {
  this.setState({name: tex});
}
```

Comment: Danke! Works now as needed

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is definitely possible. Your idea of passing the function from the main component was right, but to achieve what you are trying to do, you could pass a parameter to the function, like this:

```
  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({name: e.target.value});
  }
```

Notice that I have added the `e` as a parameter to your `handleClick` function. This is the click event received from clicking the button. We then set the state equal to the value from this event.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert `SubComp` to functional component and pass it `handleClick` which you defined inside `MyComponent` as props:

```
const SubComp = ({handleClick}) => {
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
}
```

Then pass it handleClick method like so: `<SubComp handleClick={this.handleClick} />`